# Protected Routes using UseEffect

Tags: reactjs, node.js, react-router

I'm encountering a state problem where my states are not updating when passed through my PrivateRoute.jsx

This is my App.jsx

```
  const [isUserLogged, setIsUserLogged] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getUserID = async () => {
      try {
        await Axios.get("http://localhost:3001/verifylogin").then((res) => {
          if (res.data !== "User not found") {
            setIsUserLogged(true);
          } else {
            setIsUserLogged(false);
          }
        });
      } catch (error) {}
    };
    getUserID();
  }, []);

  const router = createBrowserRouter(
    createRoutesFromElements(
      <Route path="/" element={<RootLayouts />}>
        <Route index element={<LandingPage />} />
         <CODE BELOW>
      </Route>
    )
  );

  return <RouterProvider router={router} />;
```

**CODE BELOW:**

I've tried three things:

**1st in App.jsx**

```
      <Route
          path="/admindashboard"
          element={!isUserLogged ? <Navigate to="/" /> : <Dashboard />}
        />
```

**2nd in PrivateRoutes.jsx**

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ children, privateRole }) => {
  const [isAuthorized, setIsAuthorized] = useState(false);
  Axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
  useEffect(() => {
    Axios.get("http://localhost:3001/verifylogin").then((res) => {
      if (res.data !== "User not found") {
        console.log(res.data.role);
        setIsAuthorized(res.data.role === privateRole);
      } else {
        setIsAuthorized(false);
      }
    });
  }, []);

  return isAuthorized ? children : <Navigate to="/" />;
};

export default PrivateRoute;
```

and **3rd in PrivateRoutes.jsx**

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ children, privateRole, userRole, isUserLogged }) => {
  console.log(privateRole, userRole, isUserLogged);

  Axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
  useEffect(() => {
    Axios.get("http://localhost:3001/verifylogin").then((res) => {
      if (res.data !== "User not found") {
        setUserDetails(res.data);
      } else {
        navigate("/");
      }
    });
  }, []);
  
  if (isUserLogged && privateRole === userRole) {
    return children;
  } else {
    return <Navigate to="/" replace />;
  }
};

export default PrivateRoute;
```

Basically what/verifylogin does is it get's the available token cookie and decodes JWT token and retrieve all of the data of the user (id, role, name). The problem I'm encountering is it doesn't pass the latest state because I'm using useEffect. It only reads the first/initial state so it's always false or null. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're facing is primarily due to how you're trying to manage authentication and role-based access control in a React app using React Router v6. The asynchronous nature of state updates and HTTP requests combined with the initial render behavior in React can lead to situations where the state hasn't updated yet by the time your component decides what to render.

Here are some strategies to improve and fix the issue with your `PrivateRoute` component and overall authentication flow:

1. Centralize State and Authentication Logic
   Instead of checking authentication status in each `PrivateRoute`, consider using a global context (`AuthContext`) for managing user authentication and roles. This way, your authentication logic is in one place, and you can easily access user status across your entire app.

First, create a context for authentication:

```
// AuthContext.js
import React, { createContext, useContext, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Axios from 'axios';

const AuthContext = createContext();

export const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [isUserLogged, setIsUserLogged] = useState(false);
  const [userRole, setUserRole] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    Axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
    const verifyLogin = async () => {
      try {
        const res = await Axios.get("http://localhost:3001/verifylogin");
        if (res.data !== "User not found") {
          setIsUserLogged(true);
          setUserRole(res.data.role);
        } else {
          setIsUserLogged(false);
          setUserRole(null);
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Authentication error:', error);
      }
    };

    verifyLogin();
  }, []);

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{ isUserLogged, userRole }}>
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};

// Custom hook to use auth context
export const useAuth = () => useContext(AuthContext);
```

2. Modify `App.jsx` to Use `AuthProvider`
   Wrap your application's component tree with `AuthProvider`:

```
// In App.jsx
import { AuthProvider } from './AuthContext';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <AuthProvider>
      <RouterProvider router={router} />
    </AuthProvider>
  );
};
```

3. Update `PrivateRoute` to Use `AuthContext`
   Modify your `PrivateRoute` to consume `AuthContext` directly. This way, it automatically reacts to changes in authentication state:

```
// PrivateRoute.jsx
import React from 'react';
import { Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useAuth } from './AuthContext';

const PrivateRoute = ({ children, privateRole }) => {
  const { isUserLogged, userRole } = useAuth();

  if (!isUserLogged) {
    // User not logged in
    return <Navigate to="/" replace />;
  } else if (privateRole && privateRole !== userRole) {
    // User doesn't have the right role
    return <Navigate to="/unauthorized" replace />;
  }

  return children; // User is logged in and has the right role (if specified)
};

export default PrivateRoute;
```

4. Using `PrivateRoute`
   You can now use `PrivateRoute` in your routing configuration, knowing it will properly respond to changes in authentication state and user role:

```
// Inside your router configuration
<Route path="/admindashboard" element={
  <PrivateRoute privateRole="admin">
    <Dashboard />
  </PrivateRoute>
}/>
```

Comment: This helped for global stating the auth variable but not when loading a PrivateRoute. When I navigate to /admindashboard the process of rendering is AuthContext(null) > PrivateRoute(null) > AuthContext(value rendered). Then It won't re-render PrivateRoute with values.